# save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in django blog

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm learning Django and work on a comment system.

### Model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comment_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'comment by {} on {}'.format(self.comment_user, self.post)
```

### Views

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, status='published', publish__year=year, publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)

    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_comment = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if CommentForm.is_valid:
            new_comment = CommentForm.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.comment_user = request.user
            new_comment.save()
        else:
            new_comment = CommentForm
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'comments':comments,
        'new_comment': new_comment,
        'CommentForm': CommentForm
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', context)
```

When I try to create a new comment this error occurs

```
TypeError at /blog/2019/10/29/my-second-post/
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2019/10/29/my-second-post/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Exception Location: E:\v_envs\elkhashen\src\blog\views.py in post_detail, line 35
Python Executable:  E:\v_envs\elkhashen\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['E:\\v_envs\\elkhashen\\src',
 'E:\\v_envs\\elkhashen\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'E:\\v_envs\\elkhashen\\DLLs',
 'E:\\v_envs\\elkhashen\\lib',
 'E:\\v_envs\\elkhashen\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\elkhashen\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\elkhashen\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\DLLs',
 'E:\\v_envs\\elkhashen',
 'E:\\v_envs\\elkhashen\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 31 Oct 2019 09:50:45 +0000
```

Comment: I fixed some grammar and also formatting

Comment: `new_comment = new_comment.save(commit=False)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_comment = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if CommentForm.is_valid:
            new_comment = CommentForm.save(commit=False)   <--- THIS LINE
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.comment_user = request.user
            new_comment.save()
        else:
            new_comment = CommentForm
```

There you are calling the `save()` method on the class, not an instance. You also only supply a keyword argument.

I am unfamiliar with your greater application, so I can't really say much about what code should replace it. But probably, you should use `new_comment` at the line about the line I marked, and possibly the marked line as well.

Unless I'm mistaken, CommentFrom.is_valid is either a property, or a method. If it's a method, you're evaluating the boolean value of a function, which is always true. If it's a property, you're retrieving the property, not following it through (since you're looking at a class, not an instance). It'll also always evaluate to True.

If it's a method, that line should probably be `new_comment.is_valid()`. If a property, `new_comment.is_valid`.

Answer (score 0):

When is saving(commit=True) the instance from form need know the instance from model.

Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False). When you use a simple save() on a form, all data – including many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional method calls. For example:

```
# Create a form instance with POST data.
>>> a = Author()
>>> f = AuthorForm(request.POST, instance=a) <-- Set the instance model here

# Create and save the new author instance. There's no need to do anything else.
>>> new_author = f.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method